# Como criar essa expressão no C#

Tags: c#, winforms, matemática

A primeiro momento, o programa que fiz faz o cálculo utilizando a seguinte expressão:

```
valorComDescontos = valorTotal - (valorTotal * percentual);
```

Onde o `valorTotal` é um valor atribuído pelo usuário (uma variável), o `percentual` é um valor fixo (`0.0229`) e o `valorComDescontos` é o valor que será calculado com os JUROS (`valorTotal* percentual`).
O quê estou tentando calcular agora é o seguinte: o usuário irá inserir um valor e o programa deverá calcular como resultante o valor que tendo os descontos terá o valor inserido pelo usuário. Mudando o cálculo, cheguei à seguinte expressão:

```
valorTotal = valorComDescontos + (valorTotal * percentual)
```

Porém como a variável que eu não vou ter valor é o `valorTotal`, ela não poderia constar nos dois lados da expressão. Como calcular isso?

Exemplo (Anteriormente):

```
valorTotal = 1000; #valor que o usuário inseriu
percentual = 0.0229; #valor FIXO

valorComDescontos = 1000 - (1000 * 0.0229);
valorComDescontos = 1000 - 22,9;
valorComDescontos = 977,1;
```

Exemplo (Como é para ser calculado agora):

```
valorComDescontos = 1000; #valor que seria dado pelo usuário
percentual = 0.0229; #valor FIXO

valorTotal = 1023,44; #seria esse o valor aproximado, onde descontando o percentual, chegaria ao valorComDescontos
```

Comment: Para cálculos matemáticos eu utilizo esse framework https://ncalc.codeplex.com/ Da uma olhada, ele é muito bom e acredito que atenda a sua necessidade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Matemática básica:

```
valorComDescontos = valorTotal - (valorTotal * percentual)
```

Você terá os valores de `valorComDescontos` e `percentual`, buscando o valor de `valorTotal`. Primeiro, coloque em evidência no lado direito da igualdade:

```
valorComDescontos = valorTotal * (1 - percentual)
```

Agora, se você dividir ambos os lados por `1 - percentual`, tem-se:

```
valorComDescontos / (1 - percentual) = valorTotal
```

Ou seja:

```
valorTotal = valorComDescontos / (1 - percentual)
```

#### Exemplo:

```
valorComDescontos = 1000,00
percentual = 0,0229

valotTotal = 1000 / (1 - 0,0229)
valorTotal = 1000 / 0,9771
valorTotal = 1023,4367
valorTotal ~ 1023,44
```

Como esperado.

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu estava tentando fazer